Referencing items in resume* list renders additional text
I wanted to automate my life a little and found that the enumitem package provides a way to create custom lists which can resume counting with respect to the previous list. Without that, I'd have to explicitly manipulate the enumi counter with \setcounter and that can become painful, because it is easy to fail to count correctly. :-)
Anyway, with enumitem, continuous counting works when I use resume*. However, in doing so, it breaks the references with cleverref! When referencing an item from that list, an additional resume,, text is printed. How can I get rid of this? What am I doing wrong in the preamble or is this some kind of bug?

\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% defining theorem environments for their specialized versions
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{base@thm}[3]%
{$\;$\linebreak\noindent\mbox{$\triangleright\;\textsc{\textbf{\large #1} #2 (#3).}$}}
{\hfill$\;$\linebreak}
\makeatother

% lemma environments take a label and a name
\newcounter{lemma}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmata}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lemma}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{lemma}\begin{base@thm}{Lemma}{\thelemma}{#2}\label[lemma]{lemma:#1}\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{t@lemma:#1}}
{\end{base@thm}\noindent}
\makeatother
% referencing a lemma
\newcommand{\lemmaref}[1]{\Cref{lemma:#1}~(\ref{t@lemma:#1})}
\newcommand{\lemref}[1]{\Cref{lemma:#1}}

\newlist{passumptionslist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[passumptionslist]{label=(\alph*)}

\crefalias{asm}{passumptionslisti}
\crefalias{goal}{enumi}
\crefname{asm}{assumption}{assumptions}
\crefname{goal}{goal}{goals}
\newenvironment{assumptions}
    {\begin{passumptionslist}[label=(\alph*)]
    }
    {
    \end{passumptionslist}
  }
\newenvironment{goals}
    {\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    }
    {
  \end{enumerate}
  }

\newcommand{\IH}[1][]{I{\kern-1.5pt}H#1}
\newenvironment{passumptions}[1]
  {%
  \begin{passumptionslist}[resume*,label={$\left(#1_{\arabic*}\right)$}]%
  }
  {%
  \end{passumptionslist}%
  }
% individual cases
\newcommand{\asm}[2]{\item\label[asm]{asm:#1} {$#2$}}
\newcommand{\goal}[2]{\item\label[goal]{goal:#1} {$#2$}}
\newcommand{\asmref}[1]{\Cref{asm:#1}}
\newcommand{\goalref}[1]{\Cref{goal:#1}}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][\textbf{Proof}]%
{\restartlist{passumptionslist}\par\noindent\ignorespaces\mbox{\textsc{#1}.}$\;$\\\noindent}
{$\;$\hfill$\square$\\\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}{lemma}{Some Lemma Name}
  If
  \begin{assumptions}
    \asm{lemma}{a}
  \end{assumptions}
  then
  \begin{goals}
    \goal{lemma}{b}
  \end{goals}
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  Unfold \goalref{lemma} and introduce the assumptions.
  \begin{passumptions}{H}
    \asm{lemma0}{v\Downarrow b}
  \end{passumptions}
  What is left to show is:
  \begin{goals}
    \goal{lemma0}{c}
  \end{goals}

  From \asmref{lemma0}, get:
  \begin{passumptions}{H}
    \asm{lemma1}{a=v}
  \end{passumptions}

  Rewrite \asmref{lemma} and \asmref{lemma0} using \asmref{lemma1}:
  \begin{passumptions}{H}
    \asm{lemmap}{v=c}
    \asm{lemma0p}{a\Downarrow b}
  \end{passumptions}

  Use \asmref{lemma0p}:
  \begin{passumptions}{H}
    \asm{lemma2}{a=b}
  \end{passumptions}
  Finally, rewrite \goalref{lemma0} via \asmref{lemma1}.
  Then, \asmref{lemma2} solves it.
\end{proof}


\end{document}


Haven't really found the problem yet, but: (a) cleveref has nothing to do with this. The extra resume,, are inserted at the start of the passumptions environment, and not by the reference calls. (b) From the way you are using the passumptions environment, I don't see why you are using resume* and not just resume; with the latter the problem goes away.

@WillieWong When I only use resume, the counting is not continious for some reason but restart every time at 1 again.

Ah, I missed that. Looking at your code I think you can refactor it into something simpler and easier.

This answer addresses why resume,, is printed.
Fundamentally there are two things that run into each other.
The [resume*] lists break when there's no antecedent
You can see this behavior with the following simple MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
        \item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Why does this break? To enable resume*, the enumitem code has to pass the list configuration from the previous issuance of the list to the next time the list is called. It does so by setting \enit@resumekeys@<list> (where <list> is replaced by the name of the list, i.e. enumerate or passumptionslist) to (essentially) what was passed as the optional argument to the enumitem list. This would performed at the end of the list, so when \end{enumerate} is encountered in the example above. And no default value is created; so before the list was called the very first time, the macro \enit@resumekeys@<list> is undefined.
Now, when resume* is passed to a list, enumitem tries to load the config from the last call to the list, and so it peeks into \enit@resumekeys@<list>. Notably, it does so using a \csname ... \endcsname construction, so when \enit@resumekeys@<list> is undefined this doesn't error out (with the undefined macro error). When you use \csname ... \endcsname to access an undefined macro, it always return \relax.
To allow the keys in the current call to override keys previously specified, enumitem prepends this to the optional arguments. So after processing the resume* in the MWE, the effective optional argument becomes \relax,resume.
But now, to process the list of options, enumitem needs to process a comma separated list one item at a time. It does so using a standard trick. It defines a macro using
\def\enitkv@do#1,{%
    \ifx\relax#1\empty\else
    \enitkv@split#1==\relax %% This processes the key, ignore it for now
    \expandafter\enitkv@do\fi}

The macro is delimited with a comma. So when fed a list comma separated list, it will eat the next string of characters until the next ,; it will process that string of characters, discard it (and the comma), and do the same thing again for the next argument.
How does this macro know how to stop? It stops when it encounters \relax. And in practice, this macro is called through
\enitkv@do#2,\relax,

where #2 is the list of optional arguments. Now you see the problem, when you use resume* without antecedent, the above macro, when called, processes
\enitkv@do\relax,resume,\relax,

When the first \relax hits, the macro terminates. So what we have left is a dangling
resume,\relax,

Since these are not the argument to any macros, they are processed as text. And as \relax is a no-op, when printed this becomes
resume,,

that you see.
Groups
But you say, wait a second, you've defined also the assumptions environment in terms of passumptionslist, and you have called it before calling the first passumptions in your code. Doesn't this mean that there should in fact be an antecedent?
To which you should compare the following two MWEs.
MWE 1 (no group)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Test
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
        \item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

MWE 2 (with group)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Test
\end{enumerate}
\egroup

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
        \item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

MWE 1 will behave properly, but MWE 2 will behave improperly. So what's going on here?
The following is a feature in enumitem, though I am not sure whether it is a good idea. When saving the current options in a list, enumitem behaves differently in four different cases.

When you have a series option, that is not a resume or a resume*, the code saves the both the current counter value and the current optional arguments using \global\def.
When you have a series option that is also a resume or a resume*, the code saves only the counter via \global\def, but it does not save the current optional arguments.
When you do not have a series, but has a resume*, the code saves only the counter via \global\def, but it does not save the optional arguments.
When you have a plain list that is neither a series nor a resume* (but strangely enough, resume is ok here), the code saves both the counter and the optional arguments using \def.

This causes several interesting side-effects.

If you wrap \begin{enumerate}[resume]...\end{enumerate} in a \newenvironment, then the fourth case is triggered. But as environments are grouped, the \def doesn't propagate out of the environments. This explains why the numbering is wrong as you observed in this comment.
Using your original code as reference, as you wrapped \begin{passumptionslist}...\end{passumptionslist} in the assumptions environment defined via \newenvironment, when you call \begin{assumptions}...\end{assumptions}, the package does try to save the current counter and list options at \end{passumptionslist}, but as we are in case 4, these are made via local definitions, so as soon as we hit \end{assumptions} these are lost.


The first issue identified above is a bit of a weird edge case: normal usage of enumitem should not call [resume*] on a list that has not been previously used. That said, this edge case can be fixed simply by using a different token to demarcate the end of the list in \def\enitkv@do#1,.
The second issue is in fact documented (though somewhat poorly). In the current version of the enumitem documentation, that resume is local is mentioned in passing in section 3.3. Though this funky interaction with resume* is not clearly documented (and definitely should be).

I reported the first issue to the maintainer https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/issues/48

Thank you very much for all your hard efforts, this is a phenomenal answer!

I think the use of an underlying passumptionslist that gets wrapped in various environments is unnecessary. It is better to just define everything as \newlists.
%%%% UNTIL ANNOUNCED, SAME AS YOUR CODE %%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% defining theorem environments for their specialized versions
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{base@thm}[3]%
{$\;$\linebreak\noindent\mbox{$\triangleright\;\textsc{\textbf{\large #1} #2 (#3).}$}}
{\hfill$\;$\linebreak}
\makeatother

% lemma environments take a label and a name
\newcounter{lemma}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmata}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lemma}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{lemma}\begin{base@thm}{Lemma}{\thelemma}{#2}\label[lemma]{lemma:#1}\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{t@lemma:#1}}
{\end{base@thm}\noindent}
\makeatother
% referencing a lemma
\newcommand{\lemmaref}[1]{\Cref{lemma:#1}~(\ref{t@lemma:#1})}
\newcommand{\lemref}[1]{\Cref{lemma:#1}}

%%%% CHANGES BELOW %%%%
% 1. Removed passumptslist
% 2. Removed your crefaliases

% The crefname are kept
\crefname{asm}{assumption}{assumptions}
\crefname{goal}{goal}{goals}

% 3. Defined assumptions, passumptions, and goals directly as new lists
\newlist{assumptions}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{passumptions}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{goals}{enumerate}{1}

% 3. (cont'd) and set their formatting directly
\setlist[assumptions]{label=(\alph*)}
\setlist[goals]{label=(\roman*)}

% 4. Set the format for passumptions; define macro to change the label.
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setPassLabel[1]{\gdef\@passLabel{#1}}
\setlist[passumptions]{resume,label={$(\@passLabel_{\arabic*})$}}
\makeatother

%%%%% BELOW AGAIN UNCHANGED, EXCEPT MARKED LINES %%%%%%%
\newcommand{\IH}[1][]{I{\kern-1.5pt}H#1}
% individual cases
\newcommand{\asm}[2]{\item\label[asm]{asm:#1} {$#2$}}
\newcommand{\goal}[2]{\item\label[goal]{goal:#1} {$#2$}}
\newcommand{\asmref}[1]{\Cref{asm:#1}}
\newcommand{\goalref}[1]{\Cref{goal:#1}}

%%%% Make the list that is restarted the passumptions list, and not passumptionslist.
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\textbf{Proof}]%
{\restartlist{passumptions}\par\noindent\ignorespaces\mbox{\textsc{#1}.}$\;$\\\noindent}
{$\;$\hfill$\square$\\\ignorespacesafterend}


\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}{lemma}{Some Lemma Name}
  If
  \begin{assumptions}
    \asm{lemma}{a}
  \end{assumptions}
  then
  \begin{goals}
    \goal{lemma}{b}
  \end{goals}
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
        \setPassLabel{H}   %%% Set the label for the passumptions. 
  Unfold \goalref{lemma} and introduce the assumptions.
  \begin{passumptions}   %%% No more mandatory argument (Ditto below)
    \asm{lemma0}{v\Downarrow b}
  \end{passumptions}
  What is left to show is:
  \begin{goals}
    \goal{lemma0}{c}
  \end{goals}

  From \asmref{lemma0}, get:
  \begin{passumptions}
    \asm{lemma1}{a=v}
  \end{passumptions}

  Rewrite \asmref{lemma} and \asmref{lemma0} using \asmref{lemma1}:
  \begin{passumptions}
    \asm{lemmap}{v=c}
    \asm{lemma0p}{a\Downarrow b}
  \end{passumptions}

  Use \Cref{asm:lemma0p}; \asmref{lemma0p}:
  \begin{passumptions}
    \asm{lemma2}{a=b}
  \end{passumptions}
  Finally, rewrite \goalref{lemma0} via \asmref{lemma1}.
  Then, \asmref{lemma2} solves it.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
        \setPassLabel{K}
        \begin{passumptions}
                \asm{lemma3}{c}
        \end{passumptions}
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Explanations

I think it is better to define all your list environments directly as \newlists, instead of having them as \newenvironments wrapping the list passumptionslist. The reason is that this way you have the consistency to use the enumitem interface to modify the lists either on the fly via optional arguments or globally using \setlist, increasing flexibility on how you can using them.

As far as I can tell the \crefalias has no impact on your code; so I removed them, especially since it is known to be problematic with hyperref potentially. What makes this fine is that you are using the optional argument to \label whenever you use \asm and \goal anyway, so \Cref will be able to pick up the type information from the optional argument.

I happen to think that using \newlists and \setlist makes the configuration of the formatting more transparent.

This is the only part we have to do some work. In your original code you defined passumptions with a mandatory argument which you use to set the label of the underlying list. I don't agree with this setting: firstly, from your code, it is evident that passumptions is used "per proof", so ideally consecutive passumptions in the same proof should have the same label type. (I think it would look weird if the items are numbered H1, H2, and then C3, D4, H5.) With that in mind, it is better to have a way to change the label globally (for all ensuing passumptions lists). Incidentally, doing so also makes it possible to code passumptions as a \newlist, since the lists created this way cannot take a mandatory argument.
With this design philosophy, we create a command to set the labeling symbol/character for passumptions, and use that symbol in configuring the formatting of this list. I also added the resume key since this list is meant to be resumed, until it gets reset at the beginning of every proof.



In view of the fact that you are hard coding \asm and \goal to print the second argument in math mode, I am also wondering whether it would make more sense to just define the goals and assumptions not as lists but as displayed math environments.

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it does not explain why it prints resume,,, I'd really like to know whats wrong there. This is why I don't accept your answer, to keep the question open. Nevertheless, I'm thankful for your potential workaround and gave you an upvote accordingly.

I will write a separate answer about why resume,, is printed.
